# PyQt5 - Why doesn't the QMainWindow I created with QtDesigner show up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

So I tried to make a simple hello world script using QtDesigner and exported it to qthelloworld.py with pyuic5:

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\qtdesigner_test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 771, 551))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuI_have_typed_here = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuI_have_typed_here.setObjectName("menuI_have_typed_here")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuI_have_typed_here.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello World!"))
        self.menuI_have_typed_here.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "I have typed here"))
```

Then I made a very simple script to run it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from qthelloworld import Ui_MainWindow

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now... I've manually created PyQt5 applications with the same setup I have so it SHOULDN'T be a problem to run, but I'd like to use QtDesigner to at least see whether it would help my life at all. But the goddamn thing only very briefly flashes the mainwindow widget before closing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me, and there's no reason why it shouldn't. Are you sure that's the actual code you're running? How are you running it? If you're using an IDE, that's often the issue: try running the code in a standard terminal / command-window instead. If that doesn't fix the problem, please state the platform you are testing on and the *specific* versions of Qt5 and PyQt5 you are using.

Comment: Also, ensure that you're actually running the script with *those* files: you may be running the wrong script, or from a path that includes *another* `qthelloworld.py` file (or `qthelloworld` folder). Try to copy those two files in a *new* and separate directory, then run it again, and it will probably work.

Comment: It was the IDE. Worked perfectly from the terminal. Didn't think of the possibility of the problem lying in the IDE due to it running my other hard-coded PyQt5 apps correctly. Thanks! (now I just need to find out what the **** is wrong with my IDE, but that's a non-critical issue).